# Dynamic combination of multiple PredicateSpecification with JpaSpecificationExecutor with Micronuat data for MongoDB

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-data

How can I append all the PredicateSpecification or QuerySpecification using JpaSpecificationExecutor in MongoDB with Micronaut data?

**Predicate**

```
public class DiscountSpecification {
    final static BeanIntrospection<Discount> introspection = BeanIntrospection.getIntrospection(Discount.class);
    static String[] discountProperty = introspection.getPropertyNames();

    public static PredicateSpecification<Discount> DiscountIdEquals(ObjectId DiscountId) {
        return (root, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(discountProperty[0]), DiscountId);
    }

    public static PredicateSpecification<Discount> DiscountCodeEquals(String DiscountCode) {
        return (root, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(discountProperty[1]), DiscountCode);
    }
}
```

Now based on the condition I want to append all the predicate

```
@Introspected
public record QueryBuilderSpecification() {
    public static PredicateSpecification<Discount> QueryBuilder(DiscountFilterModel discountFilterModel){
        PredicateSpecification<Discount> predicateSpecification = null;

        if (discountFilterModel.getId() != null){
            predicateSpecification =  DiscountIdEquals(new ObjectId(discountFilterModel.getId()));
        }
        if (discountFilterModel.getDiscountCode() != null){
            predicateSpecification =  DiscountCodeEquals(discountFilterModel.getDiscountCode());
        }
        return predicateSpecification;
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't append for both the condition. Quite not sure how to combine both if both are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to use `DiscountIdEquals(...).and(DiscountCodeEquals(..))`.

Your example can be used with `PredicateSpecification.ALL` as the initial state and then have:

`predicateSpecification = predicateSpecification.and(DiscountIdEquals(...))`.

There are some examples in the test apps:
https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-data/blob/master/doc-examples/mongo-example-java/src/test/java/example/PersonRepositorySpec.java#L50

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code [PredicateSpecification](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-data/blob/master/data-model/src/main/java/io/micronaut/data/repository/jpa/criteria/PredicateSpecification.java) you can `and` & `or` specifications together. As demonstrated in the [Micronaut Data User Guide](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/#specifications)

Comment: Yes, I understand your point, however, for the above code how can I combine if both the condition are matched.

Comment: How do I initialize the PredicateSpecification, so that the above condition matched. Since it is a interface and I don't know the implementation of that interface